# Line management in a text editor

Tags: c++, winapi, data-structures

I've been working on a text editor for some time. I made a custom edit control, from scratch, and I've got the basics down now. The problem I am facing is regarding line management. Since, my program relies on dividing the input text into lines(the text is printed line by line), line management is pretty important. I was using std::vector to store the line positions. I am using a Piece Table for my text processing, but for the sake of simplicity, let's say that I have an array of characters. I add/insert an element into the line vector every time the user presses enter. The issue is that every time the user inserts a character, the whole structure is disturbed. For example :

```
         0   1   2   3   4   5    6   7   8   9   10
text = ['h','e','l','l','o','\n','W','o','r','l','d']
state of line vector : 
line[0] = 0 
line[1] = 6
```

Let's say the user inserts a character('x') after the  text[2]:

```
         0   1   2   3   4   5    6   7   8   9   10  11
text = ['h','e','l','x','l','o','\n','W','o','r','l','d'] 
state of line vector : 
line[0] = 0 
line[1] = 6
```

Because of the insertion, I would need to update the value of each element in the lines vector after the current line. The same for deletion. If there are 1000 lines in a program and the user edits the first line, it would be quite inefficient to update all 999 elements(except the first one).

What I was thinking of was to keep each line independent of each other. But that would lead to complications when an existing line is divided into two lines. So I'd like to know what's a good way to go about the problem?

Edit: 
Just to clarify, I am using a data structure called Piece Table. I am not using an array of characters. Here is what a piece table data structure is :
http://www.cs.unm.edu/~crowley/papers/sds.pdf

Comment: Clearly vector<> is the wrong choice of data structure if you want to support cheap inserts.  O(n) complexity.  Have you considered list<>?

Comment: @HansPassant if you mean storing a line per element in the list, that would be expensive for moving from one line to another (though admittedly inserting a line is probably more common than moving from one line to another)

Comment: You haven't really described the problem that you're trying to solve. For instance, do you need O(1) access to the Nth line, or will O(N) do? (If so, you could simply keep the lengths of the lines in your vector, and add them up where necessary.)

Comment: @Neil 
I am looking for the a relatively efficient way to implement line management, while keeping in mind that I require the length of each line a fair number of times for certain operations. In the current approach I'm using, it is simple enough to calculate the length of a line using the offset. But it appears to be inefficient to adjust the value of each element in the vector after inserts.

Comment: Focus on how the program gets used.  Make next, previous, last, first line cheap.  Commonly used editor commands.  Page up/down, a bit harder but barely.  Jump to an arbitrary line, uncommon.  Best data structure is a doubly-linked list with a pointer to the current line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The classic data structure used by many editors is the "[Gap Buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer)". This basically has a working space that lives around the cursor where activity happens so that the local operations happen quickly. Then, when the cursor moves, the gap will, assuming a change happens, move with it.

As far as line calculations, the modern systems are fast enough where you can pretty much simply scan the buffer and look for lines. The nice thing is that you don't need to do this on most operations, so you refrain from doing it all the time. Also, there's a difference between physical lines in the buffer (i.e. collections of characters ending with an EOL marker) and soft lines (ala word wrap, etc.). Consider a modern word processor where paragraphs are routinely a single "line" but wrap to the page margins. Of course, you can handle this either way.

Finally, for most operations on the keyboard, you can simply use relative positions (i.e. if you insert a new line, then it's straightforward to add a new line marker to a line array, since you already know the point you are at within the buffer). But when you do, say, a large paste operation of several lines, it's likely faster to just cram it all in and recalculate the entire buffer (as an alternative, you could always break the paste up in to lines, and insert them one by one behind the scenes, just like a normal line).

For huge huge buffers, or slow slow computers, you may want to consider not worrying so much about the global state (exactly how many lines are in the buffer, exactly what line you might be on, etc.) at any one point and kick off that kind of recalculation in to the background. Most likely the pause will be minor (but annoying if you're typing), and will catch up as soon as the human simply pauses to catch their thoughts. Clearly this can complicate the design and you'll likely be ok using brute force on modern hardware for the time being.

Comment: A "Piece Table" is also a very commonly used data structure in text editors.  The paper the question refers to describes and compares several different data structures used by text editors to store the text, including both Gap Buffers and Piece Tables.  Sadly, the image links in the paper have gone stale, but it holds up remarkably well given its age.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question, you're keeping track of the positions of the lines with an auxiliary data structure along these lines:

```
line  offset  length
   0       0      65
   1      65      30
   2      95      50
   3     145       1
   4     146      13
 ...
```

If the length of line n changes by d, then you have to update the offset of all of the remaining lines by d.  And that's slow when there are a lot of lines.

You could keep track of landmarks.  Instead of offsets being from the beginning of the sequence, you have them be relative to some landmark.

Supposed you create a landmark for every 100 lines.  The first hundred lines are tracked just the same, since the first landmark is at the beginning of the file.  But the next hundred lines simply have offsets, and the landmark has the absolute offset from the beginning of the file for line 100.

So when you change the length of a line, you only need to update the offsets for the rest of the lines in that landmark, plus the offsets of the remaining landmarks.  That's still O(n), but there's a pretty big divisor which will make it faster.

But we can do better.  Instead of just maintaining a list of landmarks, suppose we put them in a tree, where the leaves of the tree are your line, and the root represents the entire file.  To find the offset of a given line, you add the offsets of all its ancestors together.  And if a line changes, you simply update one node and its ancestors.  This gives O(log n), at the cost of some bookkeeping.  The space overhead is not significantly worse than the doubly-linked list you're already using.

Answer (score 1):

Vector will work fine.

Consider having the line allocated dynamically, and having the vector store a pointer to the line.   Moving a bunch of pointers to line is much cheaper than moving the lines themselves.

You also might want to consider some sort of [Gap Buffer techniques.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gap_buffer)